# Python, typed text and pasted text produce different results. Why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've programmed a palindrome tester in python and when a certain palindrome containing double quotes is entered manually, the program will rightly recognize it as a palindrome. When I copy and paste the same line of text, however, the program fails to remove the double parentesis before comparing the string with its backwards counterpart.

Here's the code:

```
  ### Palindrome Test ###

  import string                               # class which includes all punctuation characters 

  word = raw_input("Please enter a word or phrase:\n")

  if (len(word) <= 1):                        # if 0 or 1 character input
      print 'Sorry, ' + '"' + word + '"' + ' is too short to be a palindrome.'

  else:

      tword = word.lower()                    # make input lowercase so capital letters don't cause problems, assn to new var

      tword2 = tword.replace(' ','')          # replace spaces with empty strings to remove space asymmetry

      tword3 = list(tword2)                   # break lowercase, spaceless input into list of characters, assn to new variable

                                              # ditch punctuation in list 
      tword3 = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in tword3]

      fword = ''.join(tword3)                 # gives us a lowercase, spaceless, punctuationless forward string

      tword3.reverse()                        # reverse list of characters

      bword = ''.join(tword3)                 # rejoin backwards list, assn to new variable

      if bword == fword:                      # check equivalence of backwards and forwards lowercase, spaceless, punctuationless input
                                              # if equivalent, print 'yes' message with original input
          print 'YES, ' + '"' + word + '"' + ' is a palindrome.' 

      else:                                   # else, 'no' message with original input
          print 'NO, ' + '"' + word + '"' + ' is not a palindrome.'
```

When, for example, '"Desserts, sis?" (Sensuousness is stressed).' is typed in as the input, it rightly returns the 'yes' message. When I paste it, it gives a 'no' message.

What's going on?

EDIT:
I've found that pasting from this site or a word document does not give me a problem. Pasting from this page (http://www.palindromelist.net/Desserts-sis-Sensuousness-is-stressed/) does produce the wrong output, however.

Comment: Please fix your indentation; your first `else:` statement would lead to a syntax error for example because the next line is not indented.

Comment: That's why I made it a comment, not an answer. The indentation error made it hard for anyone to figure out your code. Your indentation *still* is incorrect, btw, the code, as written, will *not* run.

Comment: I've fixed up the indentation to at least be consistent. Please do review, I can only guess at what your indentation should be.

Comment: `tword3 = [s for s in tword3 if s]` does nothing. There are not 'empty strings' in that, each `s` is a character, which will always evaluate to True in `if s`.

Comment: The `list()` in `''.join(list(tword3))` is redundant.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem; try stripping the input, perhaps there is *other* whitespace (apart from `' '`).

Comment: I would guess that your double quotes are probably something other than the normal `"` characters if you're pasting them in and they aren't being matched by your check.  something like Word likes to change them to other chars `“...”` sometimes called smart quotes.  Though I'm not sure it would be accepted by python at all.  or maybe you have an extra space at the beginning or end

Comment: Martin, I'll try to format it correctly and remove redundancy. Apologies, I'm very new at this.

Comment: I'm going to suggest that this gets moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com, as it works fine for me, it just needs some cleanup.

Comment: Posted relevant edit and fixed formatting (I think).

Answer (score 2):

Study this example. Your code works fine, this is just cleaned up a bit:

```
from string import punctuation

def is_palindrome(word):
    if len(word) <= 1:                              
        raise Exception("Sorry, '%s' is too short to be a palindrome" % word)

    lowered = ''.join(word.lower().split())
    filtered = filter(lambda x: x not in punctuation, lowered)                                  
    return filtered == filtered[::-1]
```